# How to add a link/url to the the task assignment email body?

Tags: sharepoint, visual-studio-2013, workflow, sharepoint-2013, workflow-foundation

I'm currently creating a SharePoint 2013 workflow by using visual studio 2013.
in the workflow I assign tasks to multiple users by making use of the CompositeTask workflow activity.
I would like to add a ling to the task form in the body of the assignment email.

When using the SingleTask workflow, the output of the activity provides a task item ID which can be used when construction a link/url to the task edit form, but there is no such output.

How can I add a link to the task form in the body of the email?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found this link just after I posted my question:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.workflowservices.activities.taskemailtokens_fields.aspx

It has a bunch of tokens you can use inside the body of the emails